# Query @ElementCollection in an @Entity with a Collection

Tags: java, jpa, jpql

Let's say that I have an @Entity (JPA 2.0)

```
@Entity    
class Entry {
        @ElementCollection
        Set<String> users = new HashSet();
        @ElementCollection
        Set<String> groups = new HashSet();
}
```

How can I query it to find all Entries where users is "John" and groups are "Foo", "Bar" and "FooBar"?

Comment: Will you answer control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using something like this

```
@Query("SELECT DISTINCT e FROM Entry e WHERE :user MEMBER OF e.users AND :groups in e.groups")

List<Entry> yourQuery(@Param("user") String user, @Param("groups") List<String> groups);
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked!
To be honest, I tried that before, but on Glassfish 3.1.2.2 with EclipseLink 2.3.1 it didn't work. After upgrade to Payara 4.1 it works like a charm.

Comment: ":groups in e.groups" is invalid for standard JPQL. You cannot do "collection IN collection". See the JPA spec section 4.6.9